# Openstack Wallaby: The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

In a fresh openstack installation Nova refuses to work:

```
root@moscontrol:~# openstack hypervisor list
The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.
 (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-f2da21b3-fca8-408c-83ba-bf74f132c6d6)
root@moscontrol:~#
```

`openstack token issue, openstack image list` commands work.

Attached my nova.conf:

```
root@moscontrol:~# cat /etc/nova/nova.conf
[DEFAULT]
my_ip = 192.168.2.91
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:mypw@moscontrol:5672/
##log_dir = /var/log/nova
lock_path = /var/lock/nova
state_path = /var/lib/nova
[api]
auth_strategy = keystone
[api_database]
#connection = sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova_api.sqlite
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:mypw@moscontrol/nova_api
[barbican]
[cache]
[cinder]
[compute]
[conductor]
[console]
[consoleauth]
[cors]
[cyborg]
[database]
#connection = sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:mypw@moscontrol/nova
[devices]
[ephemeral_storage_encryption]
[filter_scheduler]
[glance]
api_servers = http://moscontrol:9292
[guestfs]
[healthcheck]
[hyperv]
[image_cache]
[ironic]
[key_manager]
[keystone]
[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://moscontrol:5000/
auth_url = http://moscontrol:5000/
memcached_servers = moscontrol:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = Default
user_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
username = nova
password = mypw
[libvirt]
[metrics]
[mks]
[neutron]
auth_url = http://moscontrol:5000
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
region_name = RegionOne
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = mypw
service_metadata_proxy = true
# --- METADATA_SECRET
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = abcdefghijklm
[notifications]
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/nova/tmp
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[pci]
[placement]
region_name = RegionOne
project_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
auth_type = password
user_domain_name = Default
auth_url = http://moscontrol:5000/v3
username = placement
password = mypw
[powervm]
[privsep]
[profiler]
[quota]
[rdp]
[remote_debug]
[scheduler]
[serial_console]
[service_user]
[spice]
[upgrade_levels]
[vault]
[vendordata_dynamic_auth]
[vmware]
[vnc]
enabled = true
server_listen = $my_ip
server_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
[workarounds]
[wsgi]
[zvm]
[cells]
enable = False
[os_region_name]
openstack =

root@moscontrol:~#
```

The debug output e.g. for `openstack server list`

```
Instantiating compute api: <class 'openstackclient.api.compute_v2.APIv2'>
Instantiating identity client: <class 'keystoneclient.v3.client.Client'>
REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://moscontrol:9292 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: openstacksdk/0.55.0 keystoneauth1/4.3.1 python-requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.10"
Starting new HTTP connection (1): moscontrol:9292
http://moscontrol:9292 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 300 957
RESP: [300] Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 957 Content-Type: application/json Date: Sun, 03 Oct 2021 19:47:44 GMT
RESP BODY: {"versions": [{"id": "v2.9", "status": "CURRENT", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.7", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.6", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.5", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.4", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.3", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.2", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.1", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}, {"id": "v2.0", "status": "SUPPORTED", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://moscontrol:9292/v2/"}]}]}
Image client initialized using OpenStack SDK: <openstack.image.v2._proxy.Proxy object at 0x7f643a75df40>
search options: {'reservation_id': None, 'ip': None, 'ip6': None, 'name': None, 'instance_name': None, 'status': None, 'flavor': None, 'image': None, 'host': None, 'tenant_id': None, 'all_tenants': False, 'user_id': None, 'deleted': False, 'changes-before': None, 'changes-since': None}
REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://moscontrol:8774/v2.1/servers/detail -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA256}c82af5b425d7316f537491019f50eeeea875dcedcdf57c709e817a3cb18e4b25" -H "X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version: 2.1"
Starting new HTTP connection (1): moscontrol:8774
http://moscontrol:8774 "GET /v2.1/servers/detail HTTP/1.1" 503 218
RESP: [503] Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 218 Content-Type: application/json Date: Sun, 03 Oct 2021 19:47:44 GMT X-Compute-Request-Id: req-32ac8727-73ae-43f5-b30c-679551d6bd72 X-Openstack-Request-Id: req-32ac8727-73ae-43f5-b30c-679551d6bd72
RESP BODY: {"message": "The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />\nThe Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.\n\n", "code": "503 Service Unavailable", "title": "Service Unavailable"}
GET call to compute for http://moscontrol:8774/v2.1/servers/detail used request id req-32ac8727-73ae-43f5-b30c-679551d6bd72
The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.

 (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-32ac8727-73ae-43f5-b30c-679551d6bd72)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cliff/app.py", line 401, in run_subcommand
    result = cmd.run(parsed_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osc_lib/command/command.py", line 39, in run
    return super(Command, self).run(parsed_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cliff/display.py", line 115, in run
    column_names, data = self.take_action(parsed_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstackclient/compute/v2/server.py", line 2359, in take_action
    data = compute_client.servers.list(search_opts=search_opts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/novaclient/v2/servers.py", line 932, in list
    servers = self._list("/servers%s%s" % (detail, query_string),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 253, in _list
    resp, body = self.api.client.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 395, in get
    return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 78, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body, url, method)
novaclient.exceptions.ClientException: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.

 (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-32ac8727-73ae-43f5-b30c-679551d6bd72)
clean_up ListServer: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.

 (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-32ac8727-73ae-43f5-b30c-679551d6bd72)
END return value: 1
root@moscontrol:~#
```

I am running out of ideas to find my mistake, any help is appreciated

Comment: It looks like your nova api service is not running, keystone is also reported as down although you mention a `token issue` worked? Can you verify and see if apache is running and then execute a `openstack user list` or something similar? And then also check if nova-api is running.

Comment: The issue looks to be with keystone, so you need to confirm that keystone is working correctly. This will prob be running under wsgi via apache. I would check the logs for keystone.
It may also be an issue with haproxy 

You would need to check keystone_wsgi_main.log or keystone_wsgi_admin.log, there will also be a log in the httpd directories.